# Determine width of UITextView in heightForRowAtIndexPath with auto layout

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, autolayout, uitextfield

A rather convoluted problem, looking for an elegant solution:

A `UITableViewCell` subclass has a `UILabel` on the left and a `UITextView` on the right. Both label and text view have **dynamic content**. I am using the text view rather than another label because I need the address link recognition.

The label has a higher compression resistance than the text view, so that its right edge will expand towards the right as needed (up to a certain limit). The text view's width will in turn be compressed. The text view is set to word wrap to **expand downward**.

Because a text view is a itself a `UIScrollView`, the normal automatic dimension mechanism of a dynamically sized table view cells view **will not work** (i.e. using `UITableViewAutomaticDimension`). Thus, I tried to implement `heightForRowAtIndexPath`. To determine the necessary height, I *thought* just need:

- The **text** in the label, plus its **attributes**
- The **text** in the text view, plus its **attributes**
- The **width** of the table view (as it is "plain" rather than "grouped")

With this information, I reckoned, I can use `sizeThatFits` on helper objects to determine the necessary height.

However, I am reluctant to hard-code the horizontal margins between the label and the text view into my size calculation, so theoretically I additionally need `NSLayoutConstraint` outlets for

- The left **margin** of the label to its superview
- The max allowed **width** of the label
- The horizontal **distance** between the label and the text field
- The right **margin** of the text field to its superview

This seems really insane! While I was writing the implementation of this, I asked myself if there is not an easier way to accomplish the same. (That's why I did not yet write the code to post here.) After all, the only hard problem here is **how to get the available width for the text view**, but the way to getting there seems unduly complex.

Any ideas for a concise, elegant solution?

*Side notes: This has to be calculated before the cell is rendered to be displayed. Also, setting the text view's `scrollingEnabled` to `false` produces weird results when using `sizeThatFits`.*

Comment: *Because a text view is a itself a `UIScrollView`, the normal automatic dimension mechanism of a dynamically sized table view cells view **will not work***: Wouldn't Auto Layout be able to dynamically size the cell if you (programmatically) disable text view scrolling?

Comment: See my original side note about that.

Comment: Are the results initially weird, but fine after scrolling (off then on-screen)?  That may be a preferredMaxLayoutWidth issue related to the (storyboard) initial tableView width.  In any case, the Auto Layout system already has an equation which can determine the (text view) width. Since the width is given, can't the text view determine its own intrinsic content size, letting the layout system handle the height for you?

Comment: No, because of the nested scroll view issue. The text view does not "need" more space because its content is *potentially*  scrollable (regardless of the actual setting).

Comment: Have you considered putting the 2 items in `UIStackView(s)`?